# Marginal PDF of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

X and Y have joint PDF of

$f(x,y) = 4/π,  0 ≤ x ≤ 1, 0 ≤ y ≤ 1, 0 ≤ x^{2} + y^2 ≤ 1$

What is P(X + Y > 1), marginal PDF of X.

I also have question, will X and Y both are independent.

Comment: This is a uniform distribution over a non-rectangular domain.  So the probability is just an area.  Draw some pictures, you can figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $A$ be the region in the first quadrant between the unit circle and the line $x+y=1$. Then,
$$
\mathbb{P}[X+Y>1] = \iint_A f(x,y)dA.
$$